# Detect Which Form Is Sending Select Element's Value | PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

Im working with php and html. My question is: How can I detect which form is sending its select element's value to action page.

```
<?php foreach($myarray as $arr){ ?>

<form name="uniqueform_<?=$arr["product_id]?>" method="post" action="action.php">
    <select name="letters">
        <option value='a'>a</option>
        <option value='b'>b</option>
        <option value='c'>c</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

---

**action.php**

```
<?php
$myselect_value = $_POST["letters"];

echo $myselect_value; //returns null;

?>
```

When I press Send button Im going to action page but select value is Null when use echo or var_dump();

I think php can't detect which form is posted to action page. How can I solve this issue? It is very annoying.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/8Rzb8/1/

Comment: i don't see why you don't do it with one form and one submit myself

Comment: As for why you're getting a null on `echo $myselect_value;`, either (1) you aren't selecting a value or (2) something totally unrelated to the code above is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the simple answer to this is name the submit buttons different names, for example

```
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
```

you have no name there

```
 <form name="form1" >
   ....
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit_frm1" />
  </form>

 <form name="form2" >
   ....
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit_frm2" />
  </form>
```

Then you just check

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_frm1'] ){
   ... do some stuff for form1
}else if(isset($_POST['submit_frm2'] ){
   ... do some stuff for form2
}
```

I should note, however it's generally a bad practice to share form element names.  So you really don't / shouldn't name those selects the same in the first place, It will make re-populating them, in the case of an error, a real pain.

Personally, I'd just name them differently, or put another way.  Prefix all your form elements with an identifier.  So

```
 <form name="frm1" >
   ....
    <select name="frm1_select" > ... </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="frm1_submit" />
  </form>

 <form name="frm2" >
   ....
    <select name="frm2_select" > ... </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="frm2_submit" />
  </form>
```

Then on the back end you can separate them with really simple code, preg_match(), explode(), substr() etc..  And generate them with equally simple code.  I can give examples of this If you need me too.

Comment: The problem here is that you must check for each name to see if it is set.  Better to use a value that will always be set and just check the value.

Comment: I have hundreds of form and I dont now which form is submitted by the user. Do I write hundreds of if/elseif statement?

Comment: The simplest solution then is to prefix all your form elements with the number of the form, say like frm1_submit, frm1_select, etc..  I would do it to all of the elements, or you will have problems with this further on.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with differently named submit buttons, or just use a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="uniqueform_<?=$arr["product_id]?>">
```

Then check `$_POST['form']`.

Comment: How about action page? What should I do whith this hidden value?

Comment: It's in the answer:  `echo $_POST['form'] . ' was submitted';`

Answer (score -1):

You need a field to identify the form in question. Example:

- add to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?=$arr["product_id]?>" />
```

- in your action.php, examine `$_POST['product_id']` to determine which form was submitted.

For example, if the product id is 7, then `$_POST['product_id']` is 7, and the form was `uniqueform_7`.

Comment: I did not give the down vote. Another answers similar to yours but how can I handle this hidden input's value in action page? Still I don't know which form is submitted?

Comment: It's in my answer. `$_POST['product_id']` will tell you which product the form went with. The form is `uniqueform_` followed by that value. For example, if the product id is 7, then `$_POST['product_id']` is 7, and the form was `uniqueform_7`.